# Cannot deploy source code despite it being correct and getting no errors

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to deploy my code to the org (authorized in IDE of course), but the `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` command fails. In the terminal, the only thing I see is

```
=== Deploy Errors
14:40:39.217 ended SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
```

What to do in such situation?

Comment: What does `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` say?

Comment: I work on Windows

Comment: If you have Git Bash, this would still work on Windows. Otherwise, you can go to Start > Run and type in `code %userprofile%/.sfdx/sfdx.log` (or replace code with another editor). The actual errors should be near the bottom of this file.

Comment: The last thing from that file that could matter is 
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"CPX-SJKC4C7TMD1","pid":9552,"log":"SfdxProjectJson","level":40,"msg":"The config file: C:\\Users\\{me}\\.sfdx\\sfdx-project.json is not schema valid\nDue to: Validation errors:\nshould have required property 'packageDirectories'","time":"2021-08-18T13:00:15.293Z","v":0}

Comment: You're not the first person who said something like this that I've heard. It's reading the wrong file (should be in your workspace folder as `sfdx-project.json`). Try updating to the latest version, and also make sure that VS code is set to have the folder where `sfdx-project.json` is stored as the root folder (try File > Open Folder).